# svn update reporting a different revision than svn log

Tags: svn

How is the below possible in SVN (1.7.9) ?

```
$ svn update
Updating '.':
At revision 3723.
$ svn log | head -10
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r3722 | .... | ....
```

I just executed `update`. Shouldn't the `log` report revision r3723 at the top (and not r3722) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`svn log` only shows the revisions that affect the file/folder you ask it about, which defaults to `.`. `r3723` must have modified some other directory than your current directory.